# Are all smooth functions bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

in my book it says that when a function f is smooth, it also means that it is bounded. I understand that a smooth function has contineous derivatives of all orders, but how can we know that the function is bounded only by knowing it is smooth?

Comment: How about $f(x)=x$...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not all smooth functions are bounded. For example, $f(x)=e^x$ is as smooth as they come, but is not bounded.

Even if you are looking at functions on a bounded interval, $\frac 1x$ is smooth, but unbounded on $(0,1)$.

You *can* produce certain restrictions for which $f$ will be bounded, however. For example, any continuous function on a compact set (for example, any continuous function on $[0,1]$) will be bounded.

---

Also, I highly doubt that your book says that if a function is smooth, it also means it is bounded. It sounds like you are misreading a sentence in the book to mean something it does not. Can you quote the book directly, and also tell us what book you are referring to?

Comment: I'd change the first line as *Not all smooth functions are bounded.*

Comment: Thank you very much! It is correct that I misread what the book said. In an earlier chapter, it stated in an example that the function was only between x=0 and x=1. I guess this also means that the function is always only defined between two boundaries, meaning that it is bounded.

Comment: @David Even then, it's only true if the function is defined on the *closed* interval $[0,1]$. A smooth function on $(0,1)$ can be unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

A smooth function on a 
$\textit{closed and bounded}$ interval is bounded. In fact the condition can be relaxed to continuous functions by the [extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).